# I can't get NSLogger successfully intergrated to my app

Tags: ios, logging

I can't get `NSLogger` working in my iOS project, or even in a new empty project.

I was in need of some logging frameworks, and I chose `NSLogger` after some comparison because its desktop viewer is exactly what I need.

I use CocoaPod in my project, so the installation is quite simple. Just add one line in the Podfile and running 'pod update' in the console will do.

I followed the instructions in `NSLogger` wiki to configure:
First, add `LoggerStartForBuildUser()` into the `main()` function;
Second, replace `NSLog()` with `LogMessageCompact()` in my code.

And then I build my project and run it on my iPhone 6 plus(with 8.2 system).
My app works fine but I have no log in the console, not a word!

I setup a few break points and make sure the right logging code did execute.
But still nothing happened as if `NSLogger` never exists.

I created a brand new empty app project and done the same installation procedure, but still no log was shown.

I really wanna know if I missed anything. Anyone who had come across similar problem like mine?

PS:My development environment is Yosemite + Xcode 6.2

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

It turns out that the NSLogger cannot connect to the desktop viewer. I had to use LoggerSetViewerHost(NULL,hostname,port) instead of LoggerStartForBuildUser().And It works like a charm.

But every time I restart the desktop viewer, the port will change. So I had to change the port in my code and re-compile. That's a little annoying.

And by default, NSLogger would redirect all the NSLog() to its log buffer. So it's normal to see nothing in the console, unless you use LoggerSetOptions(kLoggerOption_LogToConsole) to force NSLogger to copy all the logs into the console.

Comment: I had the same issue. I added LoggerSetViewerHost(NULL,NULL,50000); and enabled "Listen to Loggers on TCP port" because it is always stays the same